# ios making a button change view when text field equals string

Tags: objective-c, ios, button, if-statement, uitextfield

I am making this kind of password to skip levels in a game. But I dont know what code I need to make a button change View Controller...

---

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    if ([txt.text isEqualToString:@"passwordToSkipLevel1"]) {
   // Code to change View Controller???
  }
}
```

I am not sure if I have done it correct to far, and I am not sure how I can make it change View Controller either...

Any ideas?

Extra: Is there any method to make the password not case sensetive?

Comment: removed xcode tag / title and added ios as this isnt ide specific

Comment: @Daij-Djan You're getting awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have seems fine as far as it goes. To make the comparison case-insensitive, you can use

```
if ([txt.txt localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:@"passwordToSkipLevel1"] == NSOrderedSame) {
    // ...
}
```

To change ViewController... is this a storyboard-based design? If so, you could write

```
if ([txt.txt localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:@"passwordToSkipLevel1"] == NSOrderedSame) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueToLevel2VC" sender:self];
}
```

where `SegueToLevel2CV` is the identifier you've given the segue that goes to the next level, typed in to Interface Builder when you constructed the storyboard.

Comment: Yes, I use storyboard for all View Controllers, but I need a code to change View Controller so I can change to different views on the same button depending on what's in the textfield..

Comment: Are you sure the segue wont change view unless the text equals the password? I mean the segue wont change view when the button is clicked if there is no password?

Comment: No, the segue only occurs if you call `performSegue...` and that won't happen int he above code unless the password matches. And, thanks for the tick! Good Luck!

Comment: But when I did this, the segue what the identifier "PassLevelOne", and run it in the simulator and press the button without writing the password or writing anything in the textfield the view changed anyway... Is there something special I have to do with the Segue, Modal, Push, Custom or anyting like that?

Comment: You can have any number of segues; just write your program to execute the one you want,and not execute any of the others. If you want to edit your question with your updated code, then I'll try to come back and suggest something. But it's getting late here, don't be surprised if I've gone to bed!

Comment: Thank you for your time, I figured it out here, and thanks mate you helpep a lot! :)