# Change view when button is clicked but only if textfield = password

Tags: objective-c, ios, button, textfield, viewcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ios making a button change view when text field equals string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791217/ios-making-a-button-change-view-when-text-field-equals-string)

I have this problem here. I want the same button to change View Controller depending on whats written in the textfield...
This is my code so far:

```
 - (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
  if ([txt.text isEqualToString:@"passwordToSkipLevel1"]) {
  // Code to change View Controller to Level1?
  } else if ([txt.text isEqualToString:@"passwordToSkipLevel2"]) {
  // Code to change View Controller to Level2?
  } else if ([txt.text isEqualToString:@"passwordToSkipLevel3"]) {
  // Code to change View Controller to Level3?
  } else if ([txt.text isEqualToString:@"passwordToSkipLevel4"]) {
  // Code to change View Controller to Level4?
  } 
}
```

Here my problem is if I can only have one segue on each button, but I want one button to change View Controller to multiple different views depending on what password that is written in the textfield..

PS: If the button is pressed when there is nothing in the textfield or text that aint any correct password I dont want the button to so anything at all.

Comment: Isn't this same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791217/ios-making-a-button-change-view-when-text-field-equals-string? Why dont you update your previous question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect all your segues to the controller, and give your segues identifiers in IB and use :

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:identifier sender:nil];

Comment: @user1734802, interface builder -- in the storyboard.

Comment: But I cant for example have two segues from one button, or can I, how?

Comment: @user1734802, Make the connections directly from the controller, not the button. You can have as many as you want from the controller.

Comment: Dont I need a Navigation Controller to do that?

Comment: If you're going to use push segues, then yes. Or, you could use a tab bar controller with the tab bar hidden. The first tab, which is selected by default, would be this view with the text field, and you could use setSelectedIndex: to programmatically move to another tab.

Comment: There arent any ways to do it in a normal View Controller, creating multiple modal segues from multiple normal View Controllers to a button?

Comment: If you want to use modals, you can do it like I said. Connect the segues directly from the view controller with the text field to the different view controllers and use the method I posted in the else-if clauses.

Comment: Oh yes of course.. Thank you so much! You really helped here and I appriciate it a lot!